# FluentNHibernate error -- "Invalid object name"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm attempting to do the most simple of mappings with FluentNHibernate & Sql2005. Basically, I have a database table called "sv_Categories". I'd like to add a category, setting the ID automatically, and adding the userid and title supplied.

Database table layout:

- CategoryID -- int -- not-null, primary key, auto-incrementing
- UserID -- uniqueidentifier -- not null
- Title -- varchar(50) -- not null

Simple.

```
My SessionFactory code (which works, as far as I can tell):
            _SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure().Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005
                    .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("SVTest")))
                    .Mappings(x => x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CategoryMap>())
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
```

My ClassMap code:

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    { 
        Id(x => x.ID).Column("CategoryID").Unique();
        Map(x => x.Title).Column("Title").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.UserID).Column("UserID").Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

My Class code:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int ID { get; private set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid UserID { get; set; }

    public Category()
    { 
        // do nothing 
    }
}
```

And the page where I save the object:

```
    public void Add(Category catToAdd)
    {
        using (ISession session = SessionProvider.GetSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction Transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(catToAdd);
                Transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

I receive the error

> Invalid object name 'Category'.
>   Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid object name 'Category'.

I think it might be that I haven't told the CategoryMap class to use the "sv_Categories" table, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Table` method in your `ClassMap`.

```
public class CategoryMap : ClassMap<Category>
{
  public CategoryMap()
  {
    Table("sv_Categories"); 
  }
}
```